# PHP - Group distribution with minimal previous matches

Tags: php, algorithm, matrix

I've been struggling on the following (algorithmic?) problem for days now. I have a list of persons that I need to group evenly. Each "round" of groupings is stored so that the next time (round) I try to group people together, we group them if they were not matched together during a previous round.

Example:

- John
- Bob
- Laura
- Lucy
- Michael
- Mark

**1st round**

*Group 1*

- John
- Bob
- Laura

*Group 2*

- Lucy
- Michael
- Mark

Now for the **2nd round** we have to avoid grouping John Bob Laura together (or at least minimize it).

I came up with the solution that works for these small edge cases where I create a pairing matrix with

[John - Bob] = 1 (number of times they got paired together in previous rounds)

[Bob - Laura] = 1

etc...

I then loop through that matrix, for each person I find the lowest number of times that person got paired with someone else and add these 2 to the list. Etc, until everybody got added to that list.

I then split that list into groups of desired number (the group size is the only parameter).

I found out that this doesn't work after a few rounds or with larger "rosters".

I'm getting close to think that this might be a NP problem because I'd have to iterate many many times to find the perfect "list".

Is there an algorithm I should look into? I'm coding this in PHP but Java or pseudo code works too.

---

A roster containing 36 persons.

1st round, group size = 6

2nd round, group size = 4

I should not have someone paired with someone else more than once.

With my solution, I have around 10 pairings that happened twice.

Comment: Perhaps it will help you to know that this is an example of an Oberwolfach problem.  Here is a paper on the subject:  http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0097316502000110.

Comment: Toward the end of the question, it looks like the group size decreases with each round. Is that correct? If so, does that pattern need to continue until the group size can no longer decrease, or do you only need to do this for a set number of rounds?

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for the direction. I tried to read through the article and it seems to be very close to my problem except that I don't need to exactly have everybody matched with everybody at least once. After a few rounds I won't have a choice and will have to put people together again in a group. Just trying to minize it. It seems like this reference graph theory?  I tried to find implementation of a solution to Oberwolfach without success... That article is hard to read and understand for me...

Comment: @Don'tPanic the group size will not decrease over time, however I can change the group size at each round, so 3rd round could have a group size of 10. Also, for a round, it is possible that the last group won't have the same size than the others depending on the roster size and the group size. On that 3rd round with group size of 10, we will end up with 3 groups of 10 and 1 group of 6.